# "--watch is not supported without git/hg" with cygwin jest and git

Tags: testing, jestjs, cygwin

I would really appreciate help with this.

I have cygwin installed and set up to use the PATH from windows. This has been working great for a ton of node development, but I've recently run into an issue where when I run

```
yarn jest --watch
```

I get the following error:

```
--watch is not supported without git/hg, please use --watchAll
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have installed git and node in windows.

I have found a workaround of using the Command Prompt for running the tests, but would really like to be in one environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some consideration, I thought my workaround could be a valid answer to this question. Although, I would still like to get this working properly in Cygwin.

If you have node and git installed in windows then you can go into the Command Prompt and run `yarn test --watch` or `npm run test -- --watch` to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

--watch works only for git repositories.

if you still have issue it is yarn issue npm gives the same error too. delete your node_modules folder, update yarn or npm to the latest version, then reinstall all the packages again.

Comment: Yeah, it was/is definitely a Git repository. And the version of Git was actually higher at the time than the version of Git in my Windows environment. I think it just something more to do with NPM from Windows into the cygwin environment. Permissions or something similar are probably blocking it from running properly.

Comment: did u try to reinstall the node_modules

Comment: Yeah, what you suggested was the very first thing I tried as it has fixed the problems when working on dual booted mac+win systems or NFS systems.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long time. But i was facing the same issue and what resolved it for me was, to change the default terminal of whatever editor you're using to GIT command line. I was using VS Code and changing the terminal to GIT worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running it in a Git repo (initialised with **git init**). Otherwise it doesn't know how to get only the changed files.

If you don't want to run tests only on changed files, you can use --watchAll, which runs all the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, the reason is that I use the mv command to move the project folder, however the command was not removed .git has points such as the beginning of the file

Answer (score 0):

npm run test -- watchAll

Please use  watchAll to serve it in a continue way. It will track your changes and re-run the test automatically.

Comment: I don't recall now, but I was met with the same issue or watchAll was undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

git init
solves the problem, that way it knows the changed files